# Allow only numeric with dot separated values in textbox

Tags: html

A text box must allow to enter only numbers from 0 to 9 and the maximum length of the field is 5 and the text box must accept values upto 99.99 only.

Comment: where is your code sir ?

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0" max="99.99" step="0.01"  />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got the code to work:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
    function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
       $(document).ready(function ()
      {
         $('#Percentage1').keyup(function (event)
        {
            var currentValue = $(this).val();
            var length = currentValue.length;

            if (length == 2)
            {
                $(this).val(currentValue + ".");
            }
            else if (length == 3)
            {
                $(this).val(currentValue + "");
            }
        });
    });
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
     <input class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage1" value=""  onpaste="return false"
        onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" />
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML INPUT TAG**

`<input id="input" onblur="validate(this)"/>`

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function validate(inputField)
{
    if(inputField.value.length > 5)
        alert("Field should be less than 5 in length");
    else if(parseFloat(inputField.value) > 99.99)
        alert("value should be less than 99.99");
    else
        this.form.submit(); 
}
```